# CPack can't have AppleScript adjusted disk image AND volume icon

Tags: cmake, cpack

When customising a disk image with CMake/CPack/DragNDrop on Mac, it is kind of impossible to have an adjusted window/icons AND a custom volume icon.

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CPACK_BINARY_DRAGNDROP ON)
set(CPACK_GENERATOR DragNDrop)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "My-CPack-App-1.0.0")
set(CPACK_DMG_VOLUME_NAME "My CPack App")
set(CPACK_DMG_BACKGROUND_IMAGE "DMGBackground.png")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_ICON "VolumeIcon.icns")
set(CPACK_DMG_DS_STORE_SETUP_SCRIPT "adjust_dmg.scpt")
```

During build, the custom volume icon is visible, but vanishes after a few moments. It looks like the disk image is rewritten as soon as you have setup_script enabled. Disabling the AppleScript will create the volume icon, but the Finder window will not look as expected.

Is this a bug or intended behavior?

The CPACK_DMG_DS_STORE variant never worked for me (Icon size not correct, no background image). But if you have a tutorial how to do that, I'm open.

Example project:
https://github.com/Macintron/MyCpackDmg

Answer (score 2):

OK. I found the Answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/create-dmg/create-dmg/issues/57). Comment out or remove any occurrences of the following code in your AppleScript file:

```
update without registering applications
```